# Using mp3wrap with Python via Popen - arguments are not being executed

Tags: python, command-line, popen

I'm trying to append one mp3 to another--hundreds, actually, but I'm starting with a simplified script here and unable to get Python to work correctly with the command line (Windows). It prints out only the mp3wrap instructions as if I'd only executed 'mp3wrap' at the command line without any arguments. What I need is the full 'mp3wrap newFile.mp3 FLN1.mp3 FLN2.mp3' to be executed. Can anyone advise? Thanks.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['mp3wrap', 'newFile.mp3 FLN1.mp3 FLN2.mp3'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print stdout
```

Comment: The program and all of your arguments are supposed to be in a single string that is the first string argument passed to `Popen`, or you are supposed to pass a sequence as the first argument with each arg as a separate item. See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Thanks, Craig! Got it. And it's working.